# Integrating Protractor to Octopus deployment (CI/CD Integration)

Tags: automated-testing, protractor, continuous-integration

I have a batch file with below content:

```batch
    %1 %2 --params.validFile=%3 --params.invalidFile=%4
```

I am starting it through power shell script:

```ps
    $path= "<filePath>\start.bat"
    $args= '"<filePath>\protractor" "<filepath>/conf.js" "<filepath>/invalidfile" "<filepath>/validfile"'
    Write-Host "Executing: " $path $args
    $process = Start-Process $path $args -RedirectStandardOutput stdout.txt" -RedirectStandardError "stderr.txt" -PassThru
    $process.WaitForExit()
    if ($process.ExitCode -eq 0){
      Write-Host "protractor cmdline complete"
      Exit 0
    } else {
      Write-Error "protractor cmdline failed"
      Exit 1
    }
```

**Note:**

- ***filepath*** is the absolute path
- ***invalid*** and ***valid*** files are just parameters to the test

**Problem:**

On running this as part of octopus deployment, the logs shows  the "protractor cmdline failed" printed, but the octopus step never ends. It keeps on going forever.

**Could someone help in knowing how to integrate protractor with octopus?**

Comment: My guess? You're doing it wrong. Octopus is typically used as a deploy server, not a build server. Meaning, I would bet that the packages required for the protractor tests to run on your Octopus server do not exist and that's why it's failing. For my setup, I have a Jenkins job that runs the protractor tests. The powershell script I run in Octopus just calls out to Jenkins to start the job and then exits. The results of the Jenkins job can then be configured to report back to where ever you want. In my case, it's slack.

Comment: Hi we have manually installed all the dependencies , so the tests are running fine in the agent . The issue is only with the octopus step getting hung

Comment: @tehbeardedone And even if protractor test is failing , the question is why Exit 1 is not getting executed. " Protractor cmdline failed" message is getting printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was because the chromedriver was not exiting after test execution completes. This makes the octopus script to hang

[https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4690][1]

So the work around was to add directconnect to the conf.js

```
exports.config = {

  directConnect: true,
```

Also i fixed the powershell script as:

```
$process = Start-Process -FilePath "$ProtractorPath" -ArgumentList $args -PassThru
$process.WaitForExit()
```

Where,

```
$ProtractorPath= "<path>/protractor"
$args= '"<path>/conf.js" --params.value="bla"'
```

So now i am not executing protractor using batch file , but directly from powershell.

Comment: It makes sense to mark the answer as correct

Comment: I can mark it tomorrow only as per stack policy